# Add-Migration not creating new migration - Asp.Net - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I have used the MVC template in ASP.Net to create a new web application. Now I have added a points variable to the user.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public long Points {get; set;}
}
```

I first enabled migrations

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Now I have tried migrating using:

```
Add-Migration Points
```

Now I ran

```
Get-Migrations
```

However I still only get the initial migration.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled migrations?

Comment: @lopezbertoni yes, I have. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you post your Migrations/Configuration.cs file code?

Comment: @lopezbertoni I'm a basic programmer so my first reaction would be 'Huuuuuuh?'. But okay, I'll try.

Comment: That's why I asked for your Configuration.cs file. When you type into the PM console Enable-Migrations, it should add those files to the project. Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to lopezbertoni for guiding me via comments.
I am enlightened...

The migrations show that there are two cs files. One has the points, one has the main migration.

[image]

Comment: Glad I was able to help.